# How to read from multiple Elasticsearch indices in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I need to read data from multiple indices of Elasticsearch. But all of these indices have the same data structure.

For example:

```
val df1 = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
              .option("query", myquery)
              .option("pushdown", "true")
              .load("news_01/myitem")

val df2 = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
              .option("query", myquery)
              .option("pushdown", "true")
              .load("news_02/myitem")
```

What happens if I get the array of index names `["news_01", "news_02"]`?

How can I avoid creating `df1`, `df2` as I do now?

Comment: You mean, you want to merge the data from two indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that ElasticSearch allows you to target multiple indices at the same time during a search request, you could do something like:

```
val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
              .option("query", myquery)
              .option("pushdown", "true")
              .load("news_01,news_02")
```